# reason for structures to not hold self type?

Tags: c, struct

Please help me to figure out a very basic confusion as follows,

```
 struct node {
        struct node *next; // no compile error
 }
```

is ok, but the following gives an compile error(unknown type). I know it is wrong, but unable to figure out a clear reason.

```
 struct node {
        struct node next; // compile error, unknown type..why?
 }
```

Comment: How many bytes would a `struct node` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the struct is not fully defined at that point.   If its a pointer, it does know how big a pointer to a struct is.

and if you think about what you are trying to do, a recursive data type, its gets a tad odd, it would be an infinite recursion.

Answer (score 2):

C allows you to have pointers to incomplete types.

`struct node *next` is a forward reference to struct node, but since you're only declaring a pointer to that type, the compiler doesn't mind. This is explicitly allowed, and it enables building structures that refer to each other.

You don't need a complete type to declare a pointer. Now a member `struct node next;` you'd get an error as it is a never-ending recursion.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically, it's because a `struct` type is incomplete until the closing `}`. You can use an incomplete type to declare a pointer to it, but the the type itself.

Furthermore, it doesn't make sense to define a `struct` that has itself in it, the size of it is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is that `node` is not a complete type until you finish defining node and close it with `}` and so the compiler does not have enough information but you are allowed to have a *pointer* to an incomplete type.

The more basic reason is if `node` contained a `node` it would require infinite space since the self reference would never end. A node contains a `node` contains a `node` *ad infinitum*.

If we look at the draft C99 standard section `6.2.5` *Types* says:

> [...] incomplete types (types that describe objects but lack information needed to determine their sizes)

and also says (*emphasis mine*0:

> A **pointer type may be derived** from a function type, an object type, **or an incomplete
>   type**, called the referenced type.[...]

Answer (score 0):

It would take an infinite amount of memory to store this struct.

The struct has to be large enough to store all of it`s members.  However one of it's members is a struct of the same type, so it needs to store enough memory for two sets of members.  But wait, that inner struct contains another instance of the struct inside itself - so we have three sets of members.  And that inner contains an inner struct, which itself, contains an inner struct, and so on to infinity.

It is then logically impossible for a struct to contain itself.